# Save property with comma to CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm creating a CSV file in powershell.

Right now my code is:

```
Add-content -Path $filePath -Value "$($variable.Property)"
```

This works fine for the most part EXCEPT if the property contained a comma ie. "test, organization".
When I open up the CSV, the comma is taken with it (which is what i want) causing a extra separation. How do save "test, organization" to one column?

Comment: `Export-CSV` or `ConvertTo-Csv` should escape comma's in CSV format. If you need to escape value's with commas manually, wrap them in quotes. `Value1,"test, organization",Value3` should be three values in CSV with a comma in the middle value.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the documentation for [Export-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7), you will need to use a different delimiter, like a semi-colon.

When you read the CSV you should specify the delimiter as well: [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7).

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote your properties:

```
Add-content -Path $filePath -Value "'$($variable.Property)'"
```

Or use one of the built-in CSV commands, which automatically quote all values:

```
$foo.Bar | Export-Csv -Path $filePath
$foo.Bar| ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File -Path $filePath
```

If you just want to avoid issues with commas, you can change the delimiter between fields:

```
$foo | Export-Csv -Path $filePath -Delimiter '|'
```

Comment: I tried "`"$($variable.Property)`" and it works as it should for the first value but when i insert multiple: ie. -Value "`"$($variable.Property)`"  `"$($variable.Property2)`" `"$($variable.Property3)`" , the quotations are added to the column (ie. in the csv it looks like Property1, "Property2", "Property3". Is this normal?

Comment: @userone Yes, if the value could contain your delimiter, you would quote it. By default, `Export-CSV` quotes all values before separating them with the delimiter. It's a bit hard to tell with the formatting, but you may have too many quotes, or `Add-Content` may be taking them as separate inputs.

Comment: If you continue to have issues, can you add an example of the output you want and what you're getting? Something like: `"Orange","Apple","Banana, comma","Peach"` with more than one row and column

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on how to use out-file or add-member with some cells of the row having commas in the variable values and some not.

https://imjustanengineer.blogspot.com/2022/01/so-youre-trying-to-use-powershell-out.html

Here is a code snippet, a more detailed explanation with a full working function is in the link. $outputArr is an array of all the lines of csv data you want to write to the csv. The loop checks each line to see if it contains commas inside of the individual cell entries and puts quotes around that entry if it does. If it does not, no adjustment is necessary and then a new array is appended to afterwards.

```
$index = 0;
        foreach ($outputTemp in $outputArr)
        {
            if ($outputTemp.ToString().Contains(","))
            {
                $output += "`"$outputTemp`",";
            }
            else
            {
                $output += $outputTemp + ",";
            }

            $index++;
        
            if ($index -eq $outputArr.Count)
            {
                if ($output.EndsWith(","))
                {
                    $output = $output.Remove($output.Length - 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a diabolically simply answer after I opened a csv file in Excel and added text and commas to one column.  When I saved, closed and reopened, the column still had all the words and commas properly formatted.  So, then I opened the file in notepad++ and this is what I found:

```
column1text, column2text,"column3,text,with,commas"
```

In case it's not clear, and it took me a fair bit to recognize the little detail that makes all the difference, the opening double quote cannot have a space after the preceding comma.

```
column1text, column2text, "column3,text,with,commas"
```

splits all the words into separate columns because there is a space between

```
column2text, "column3,etc"
```

Take that space away

```
column2text,"column3,etc"
```

and everything within the double quotes stays in one column.

Example using active directory distinguishedName such as CN=somename,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=foo,DC=bar

```
$computers = get-adcomputer -filter *

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $deviceName = $computer.Name
    $dn = '"' + $computer.DistinguishedName + '"'
    $guid = $computer.objectGUID
    $lastLogon = $computer.LastLogonDate
    $serialNumber = $computer.serialNumber
    $whenCreated = $computer.whenCreated
    "$guid, $lastLogon, $deviceName, $serialNumber, $whenCreated,$dn" | add-content "c:\temp\filename.csv"
    }
```

It does not work if a space is added between $whenCreated, and $dn like so:

```
"$guid, $lastLogon, $deviceName, $serialNumber, $whenCreated, $dn" | add-content "c:\temp\filename.csv"
```

This took up an afternoon, so I hope this saves somebody some time and frustration.